# Unexpected Property Behavior

Tags: traits, enthought

The following script:

```
import sys
print ('Python version:', sys.version)
import traits
print ('Traits version:', traits.__version__)

from   traits.api import HasPrivateTraits, Property, Range
from   traits.api import cached_property


class Exposure (HasPrivateTraits):

    # external specifications ...
    duration  = Range (low=0.0, high=3600.0, exclude_low=True , exclude_high=False)
    count     = Range (low=1  , high=10000 , exclude_low=False, exclude_high=False)
    total     = Property (depends_on='duration, count')
    # internal specifications ...
    _signature_ = Property (depends_on='duration, count')

    @cached_property
    def _get_total (self):
        return self.duration * self.count

    @cached_property
    def _get__signature_ (self):
        return hash ((hash(self.duration), hash(self.count)))

    def __hash__ (self):
        # required procedure if instances are to be `set` elements or `dict` keys
        return self._signature_

exposure_1 = Exposure (duration=0.001, count=2)
exposure_2 = Exposure (duration=1    , count=2)
assert hash (exposure_1) != hash (exposure_2)
```

produces the following output:

**Python version: 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Traits version: 4.6.0.dev0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jgv\Documents\Projects\Astronomy\Imaging\hash_test.py", line 35, in 
    assert hash (exposure_1) != hash (exposure_2)
AssertionError**

If either:

- total     = Property (depends_on='duration, count')

or the @cached_property decorator preceding:

- def _get__signature_ (self):

is deactivated, no AssertionError is raised and the script completes as expected.

I am a novice traits user and would appreciate insight as to why the AssertionError is raised.

Thanks,
-jim

Comment: Another way to get it to work is remove the trailing underscore from the property name; that is, use `_signature = Property (depends_on='duration, count')`  and change the uses of the name elsewhere in the code.  My traits-fu has gotten very rusty, so I'll let one of the gurus at Enthought (hey y'all!) or elsewhere provide an answer to "why?".

Comment: Thanks Warren.  That does work.  I wonder what is special about a trailing underscore ( _signature instead of _signature_ ) other than _signature is as per the Enthought documentation.